# Why can't "L'avenue des Champs-Élysées" be written as "L'avenue de Champs-Élysées"

Tags: grammaire, sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques

Since de can also be used to show possession,i think it should be possible for this sentence to be used like this.

Comment: Because it is the name of the street. Hard to make a comparison that would sound the like while I don't know where you are living, but it would be like asking an New Yorker why we cannot name the _Fifth Avenue_ something like _Number Five Avenue_. It is a proper noun.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between *de* and *des* is whether you're including the definite article *les*. The same is true of *de la* and *du* (*de* + *le*). All of these are "possessive" (more technically genitive), but it depends on whether the second thing uses a definite article. People and cities don't, so you get "Tour d'Eiffel" and "Bois de Vincennes".

But in geographical names, we often do describe something with a definite article. For example, I'm in Montréal and the mountain here is called "**le** mont Royal". The river is "**le** fleuve Saint-Laurent". Elsewhere, we have the mountains called "**les** Laurentides" and the region in France called "**les** Bastides", plural just because there's more than one mountain and more than one bastide. So, in Paris, we have "**les** Champs-Élysées".

In these cases, common nouns that include that geographical feature use its definite article:

> Chalet du Mont-Royal

> Côte du (fleuve) Saint-Laurent

> Région des Laurentides

> Circuit des Bastides

> Avenue des Champs-Élysées